# Grid cells not showing

Tags: javascript

So I've been doing this etch-a-sketch project and made the grid with JavaScript. For this project, the grid's size should change when the user inputs a value. With my code, the grid's size changes for a moment and disappears, then [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QXH9.png) appears. I can't seem to figure out what went wrong.

https://codepen.io/sn-tin/pen/ExQXPKW

```
/* Creating Grid */
const mainGrid = document.querySelector(".main-grid");
let gridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-element");


function createGrid(rowsCol){
    for(let i = 0; i < rowsCol * rowsCol; i++){
        let createDIVs = document.createElement("div");
        createDIVs.classList.add("grid-element");
        mainGrid.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", createDIVs);

        mainGrid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${rowsCol} , 1fr)`;
        mainGrid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rowsCol} , 1fr)`;
    }

    resetGridSize(rowsCol);
}

/* Reset size of grid with user's input */
const inputGridSize = document.querySelector(".input-grid-size");
const setButton = document.querySelector(".set-btn");

function resetGridSize() {
    setButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let size = inputGridSize.value;

        if(size < 2 || size > 80 || size === null){
            alert("Invalid Number. Please try again!")
            size =16;
        }
        createGrid(size);
    })
}

createGrid(16);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call `resetGridSize(rowsCol)` from `createGrid(size)`, and doing so makes an infinite cycle of calls between the two functions. Also, although not fatal, you might consider using a document fragment to build the grid before adding to the document, to save the many dom refreshes your current code has. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I removed the resetGridSize from createGrid. But now, the page is crashing whenever I try to submit an input? Here's the updated code https://codepen.io/sn-tin/pen/ExQXPKW